# Web app for making board with lists

Tags: web-apps, information-management, planning, books, hosted

I want to organise my reading plans as groups of lists placed on a board.

Here is an example:

[image: board with multiple groups]

It is in Russian, but I think it's possible to get the idea: I need to gather lists of books on different topics, series or authors, and then mark books that I've already read. I also group them visually, placing them free on the board (for example, in blue area, upper right corner is mostly sci-fi, and bottom-right is fantasy).

Is there any hosted web app that allows such type of planning?

I tried Trello, but didn't like it (cannot freely place lists on the board, too few visual/style options in free version); is there something else? I draw the example picture with some mind-mapping tool, but I would prefer to store it on some website for quick access and editing

Comment: White bullet = unread, black bullet = read?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul , yes, I mark read and unread books.

Answer (score 2):

## [TaskBoard by kiswa](https://github.com/kiswa/TaskBoard)

> A Kanban-inspired app for keeping track of things that need to get
> done.
>
> The goal of TaskBoard is to provide a simple and clean interface to a
> functional and minimal application for keeping track of tasks. It's
> not trying to be the next Trello or LeanKit.

You can customize the boards and create diferent ones, for example. "To read", "Reading", "Read".

You find a demo [here](https://taskboard.matthewross.me/)